# How to create conditional AuthenticationProvider in Spring-Security?

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

So far I stored my username and encrypted passwords in a database.

My custom `UserDetailsService` looks up the user from a database. The passwords are stored encrypted, thus applying the `BCryptPasswordEncoder` here.

```
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(new BCryptPasswordEncoder());
    }
}
```

Problem: I now have to add an additional authentication source, that serves *unencrypted* passwords (I have no control over this). Thus, if the authenticated user could not be found in my db, I want to check on the additional source with unencrypted passwords. But how can I then disable the `BCrypt` encoder for those cases?

Comment: I'm not on my dev machine at the moment, but I believe there's a composite password encoder specifically for this use case (online migration). You can recognize Bcrypt passwords by the prefix.

Comment: @chrylis so I would have to prefix all my encoded passwords in database with `{bcrypt}`, is that correct? And then just rely on the spring defaults?

Comment: Bcrypt passwords are already prefixed by `$2a$`.

Comment: I tried it by not setting my own password encoder, so the default `DelegatingPasswordEncoder` is loaded: prefixing with `{bcrypt}` works and delegates to the brcypt encoder. Just using the plain encoded pw starting with `$2a$` does not work! Might I be doing something wrong?

Comment: I'm surprised and not quite sure what's going on, but if it works for you, great!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can configure multiple Authentication providers like below. Each authentication provider is tested in order and the one which is successful first provides the authenticated data and the others are skipped. A similar use case is implemented in a similar way where you have to first authenticate via a database and then a LDAP server ( or vice-versa) also is handled in similar manner.

```
@Autowired
public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.authenticationProvider(authenticationProviderWithEncryptedUser);
    auth.authenticationProvider(authenticationProviderWithNonEncryptedUser);

}
```

Comment: This is great. I combined this approach using two `DaoAuthenticationProvider` with each having it's own `UserDetailsService`. Whereas one is my old bcrypt service, and the other the new nonencrypted service.

Answer (score 0):

few day ago i also face this problem my legacy system data encrypted in `MD5` but new system save password in `BCrypt`

for handle this  problem i write some custom code and using `AuthenticationProvider` instead of  `UserDetailsService`

here i shear my code for you help

```
@Component
public class CustomAuthenticationProvider implements AuthenticationProvider {
    @Autowired
    LoginDao loginDao;

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder(12);
    }

    @Override
    public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {

        List<GrantedAuthority> grantList = new ArrayList<>();
        String name = authentication.getName();
        String password = ((String) authentication.getCredentials()).trim();
        try {
            UserModel user = loginDao.getUser(name);
            if (user != null) {
                if (passwordEncoder().matches(password, user.getLoginPass())) {
                //  System.out.println("------Good new & Strong password -----");
                    GrantedAuthority authority = new SimpleGrantedAuthority(user.getAuthotype().toString());
                    grantList.add(authority);
                }else if (password.equals(user.getLoginPass())) {//here i have md5 checker service , i remove it for your help 
                //  System.out.println("------old password! should be change it-----"); 
                    GrantedAuthority authority = new SimpleGrantedAuthority(user.getAuthotype().toString());
                    grantList.add(authority);
                }else {
                    throw new BadCredentialsException("Please enter a valid username and password.");
                }
                    return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(user, password, grantList);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new BadCredentialsException("Please enter a valid username and password.");
        }
        throw new BadCredentialsException("Please enter a valid username and password.");
    }

    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class<? extends Object> authentication) {
        return UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.class.isAssignableFrom(authentication);
    }

}
```

and change your `SecurityConfiguration` class code

```
@Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the current docs (https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/crypto/password/DelegatingPasswordEncoder.html), 
I just have to remove my setter of `.passwordEncoder()` to rely on the new default password delegation feature in spring.

Then prefix all of my passwords with `{bcrypt}` for my db passwords, and `{noop}` for my new plaintext passwords.